# to open up an excel file, do I need any special references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

to open up an excel file, do I need any special references?

I want to access the rows programmatically.

Comment: Please define "open": for programmatic data access, to display to user, ...

Comment: to read it programmatically, or simply to have a link for the user to click? And any version in particular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To actually work with Excel from C#, you'll probaly want to add the `Micorsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly. Watch the version, version 12 = Office 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  As for which references, you'll need to give us more information.